# How do I increment a value in a textfile using the regular Windows command-line?

Tags: windows, command-line, text-files

I'd like to keep a "compile-counter" for one of my projects. I figured a quick and dirty way to do this would be to keep a text file with a plain number in it, and then simply call upon a small script to increment this each time I compile.

How would I go about doing this using the regular Windows command line?

I don't really feel like installing some extra shell to do this but if you have any other super simple suggestions that would accomplish just this, they're naturally appreciated as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try a plain old batchfile.

```
@echo off
for /f " delims==" %%i in (counter.txt) do set /A temp_counter= %%i+1
echo %temp_counter% > counter.txt
```

assuming the count.bat and counter.txt are located in the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

It would be an new shell (but I think it is worth it), but from PowerShell it would be

```
[int](get-content counter.txt) + 1 | out-file counter.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest just appending the current datetime of the build to a log file.

```
date >> builddates.txt
```

That way you get a build count via the # of lines, and you may also get some interesting statistics if you can be bothered analysing the dates and times later on.

The extra size & time to count the number of lines in the file will be insignificant unless you are doing seriously fast project iterations!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind running a Microscoft Windows Based Script then this jscript will work OK. just save it as a .js file and run it from dos with "wscript c:/script.js".

```
var fso, f, fileCount;
var ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2;   
var filename = "c:\\testfile.txt";
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

//create file if its not found
if (! fso.FileExists(filename))
{
  f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, ForWriting, true);
  f.Write("0");
  f.Close();
}

f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, ForReading);
fileCount = parseInt(f.ReadAll());

//make sure the input is a whole number
if (isNaN(fileCount))
{
    fileCount = 0;  
}

fileCount = fileCount + 1;

f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, ForWriting, true);
f.Write(fileCount);
f.Close();
```